# Why single (flexible array) member struct declaration is only supported by [0] and not []?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, flexible-array-member

Basically:

```
struct foo_1
{
    int flexible_guy[0]; // this works
};

struct foo_2
{
    int flexible_guy[]; // this doesn't (error: flexible array member in a struct with no named members)
};
```

Is this the intended logic for some reason, an easter egg workaround for something not supported, or a compiler bug?

I'm using GCC 7.5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04, but I get the same result on a web compiler that uses GCC 9.4.0 (https://onlinegdb.com/_15wOU3UF).

Comment: What do you mean by "this works"? What does work with a zero-sized array? Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates that which works.

Comment: A zero-sized array is not a flexible array but it is a GCC extension (supported by some other compilers). A flexible array as the *only* member of a structure is not Standard C - it is a Microsoft extension (according to clang). [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc supports zero length arrays as an extension, which is why the first one is allowed.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.htm

The second case doesn't fall under this extension, so it falls back on what the C standard states, which doesn't allow an array with unspecified size in a struct as the only member.

From section 6.7.2.1p3 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Struct and Union Specifiers under the Constraints heading:

> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or
> function type (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of
> itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of itself), except
> that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
> may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union
> containing, possibly recursively, a member that is such a structure)
> shall not be a member of a structure or an element of an array.

The above gcc page on zero length arrays also mentions this:

> Flexible array members may only appear as the last member of a struct that is otherwise non-empty